# finding the maximum of all averaged results

Tags: mysql

I've got a table EmployeeDetails

```
DeptID   | EmpName |  workDate | percentage
------------------------------------------
dev         Sam       06/07/16   10%
dev         Smith     07/07/16   20%
HR          Denis     06/07/16   5%
HR          Danny     07/07/16   3%
IT          David     06/07/16   15%
IT          John      07/07/16   20%
```

Could you please help me to find a sql query that obtains the highest average(percentage) for each department and lowest average(percentage) for each department.

Thank you very much.

Comment: is it mandotary to use % symbol in percentage column with data ??

Comment: Don't store '%'. Always store data using the appropriate data type. And now it's really easy. Oh, and figure out which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: You should not store '%'...it will create misleading for Query

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT DeptID, EmpName, MAX(percentage),MIN(percentage)
    FROM employeedetails
    GROUP BY deptid;
```

Output: [SEE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4641e/1)

NOTE: You should not store '%' char in database, it can be make misleading for Query.

**Update 1**: As per your comment in answer first You want to get Average of percent department wise then you want to get max and min value of percentage department wise. You can achieve this with help of `GROUP_CONCAT` and `UNION` functions

*Try this Query*:

```
(SELECT DeptID, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(EmpName SEPARATOR ',') AS Employees, 
    AVG(percentage) AS Max_Min_AvgValue
    FROM employeedetails 
    GROUP BY deptid 
    ORDER BY percentage DESC LIMIT 1)

    UNION

(SELECT DeptID, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(EmpName SEPARATOR ','), 
    AVG(percentage)
    FROM employeedetails 
    GROUP BY deptid 
    ORDER BY percentage ASC LIMIT 1);
```

Output: [SEE DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4641e/17) for Update1

Comment: hi this query will execute fine my scenario is , average of percentage column based on group by deptId then amoung the average of percentage column which one is highest and lowest value

Comment: Your scenario is not cleared to me...You mean first you want to get Average of percent department wise then you want to get max and min value of percentage department wise... Right?

Comment: @Creditto check update 1, I modified answer and update SQLFiddle also.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
SELECT MAX(percentage) as maximum, MIN(percentage) as minimum
FROM EmployeeDetails
GROUP BY DeptId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *,max(percentage),min(percentage)
from department
group by deptid
```